# Checkstyle for subclass of BaseEvents

Tags: java, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I am using [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) plugin for Java. However I want to design a checkstyle that: **subclass of BaseEvents should only have class variables as final.**

Answer (score 0):

Please read over http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html .

Your check will have to examine the class for an extends of `BaseEvents`. You will have to make sure the correct the `BaseEvents` is given in the imports. ONce you have identified that the class meets your requirements, validate all fields to have the `final` modifier.

I recommend using http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html#Tool_to_print_Java_tree_structure to print the tree structure of your java files and how to navigate the tree and where to find things.